# VBA - Web Scraping : Instruction migration from IE to EDGE using Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, internet-explorer

I am trying to migrate the web-scraping instructions from IE to EDGE using Selenium. I noticed that there are substantial differences, so when converting an application instruction into VBE, this is:

```
ieObj.Document.getElementsByClassName ("login-button bold"). Item.Click
```

which in IE works great, I couldn't find any matches with Edge -Selenium. The first obstacle consists in the fact that the "ClassName" in Selenium does not exist so it is not possible to instantiate it with the corresponding `.FindElement`.

Is there anyone who has already solved the problem? How can I do ? Thanks for everything.

Comment: `driver.FindElementsByClass("class info")`.   Can't remember if spaces allowed with VBA Selenium. They are in `getElementsByClassName` in `SHDocVw`. Otherwise, use `FindElementsByCss` and replace the spaces in the compound class with a dot "." .

Answer (score 0):

This `getElementsByClassName ("login-button bold")` will not work, as it contains multiple spaces which means it is combination of 2 classes.

You will have to switch to CSS selector or XPath

However, If you are interested to use **CSS selector** :

You can try this :

```
getElementsByCss(".login-button.bold")
```

**Code:**

```
ieObj.Document.getElementsByCss (".login-button.bold"). Item.Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the class of the element like this `class="login-button bold"`? If so, you can try with `FindElementsByCss` to find the element by the two class names.

Sample code:

```
driver.FindElementsByCss(".login-button.bold").Item(1).Click
```

Note: You can change the number in `Item()` according to your situation. It depends on the position of the element of the class names collection.